# Toolbar overlaping with content

Tags: android, toolbar, android-toolbar

I've tried a lot of permutations but I can't for the life of me get the toolbar to "push" down "content_main" (which is a ConstraintLayout with the "NavHostFragment")

On a related note, I can't get the "connecting_overlay" to cover the toolbar (it's a FrameLayout used to obscure the screen while a connecting thing happens)

I think there are a few ways to force the spacing through either wrapping the toolbar and "content_main" in a linear layout or something but I just wanted to see if someone with more experience could outline the "Androidic" way of handling the toolbar. The official documentation seems to be either too high-level or too low-level...

Here's my "app_bar_main.xml"

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/white_50"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.MyApp" />

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <include layout="@layout/connecting_overlay" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Into your content_main included layout, put in the following attribute:

```
app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
```